# C++ polymorphic base class hierarchy design for plugins

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, linker, polymorphism

I would like to have a DLL-based plugin system in my project. Each plugin should implement abstract interface, which my application provides. In my application I treat all the classes hierarchy instances, engendered in different plugins via base polymorphic class smart pointer (this is a class, which provides interface in fact).

This is my polymorphic base class definition, aka abstract interface, it placed in header file, I would like to provide for plugins developers only.

```
class ISomeInterface{
    public:
        virtual ~ISomeInterface(); // need for base polymorphic class
            ...                  // other methods, including pure virtual
    private:
            ...

    };
```

So I need to add an implementation for destructor at least. If I place it in according source file - it leads me to additionally providing this file, or compiled library to plugin developers.

From the other side - I can put destructor implementation in header file, but then there is another issue. I have several embedded in my application plugins in different source files, using this header. When I try to compile it I will get linker error because of name conflicts in my application object files.

Is there any good practice about it?

Comment: Just put an inlined destructor there, usually this works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the definition of a member function within the class declaration lets you include the header file in diffrent files without the symbol redefinition problem.

```
class ISomeInterface{
    public:
        virtual ~ISomeInterface()
        {
            ...
        }

    private:
            ...

    };
```